# Run Robolectric tests from IDEA

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, gradle, robolectric

I'm trying to run
RobolectricSample
[RobolectricDemoProject](https://github.com/peterfriese/RobolectricDemoProject)
 project with IDEA and i got error

> Class not found: "de.peterfriese.robolectricdemo.MainActivityTest"
>   Process finished with exit code 1

but when i use gradle test command all is ok.
[this is my Junit config](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7265353/screen.png)

Answer (score 0):

now, in IDEA you have using non gradle project. That mean you can look on project structure (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S) and look on Library visibility. (Runtime, Provided,etc) also export property are exist. When library are provided or no exported, it will be absent in target apk.

Also you can build project as gradle test project. so IDEA will use your gradle test target. Build will take litle more time.

Comment: this is not working for me. @Yevgen Kulik i am using gradle and all is working from command line but i got problem when i try to run this test from IDEA
.all is ok with lib problem with specific test class

Comment: that class isn't present in android from board. You need, to change some library compile level. Could you attach screenshot. form dependency tab on project settings of test module, and real project

Comment: I guess `MainActivityTest` is the test class

Comment: I means you use some clases for test environment as you can found in build gradle the next libs are used
 instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    instrumentTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
if you have import project into IDEA like non gradle project, you should download and add to dependency both of thouse libs.